# Why does the SQL connection get blocked randomly?

Tags: sql, vb.net, git, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2 runs on Windows Server 2008 R2 in a domain and using the same 
domain accounts (Windows authentication) to allow the connection between the client PCs and the SQL Server, created and ODBC source(System DSN named Renta_Equipos) which connects to the database and and the solution. Example: BD <---- DSN <---- WinForm Solution.

**The Connection String is an Application.Settings:**

> **Name:** ConnectionString_RentaEquipos
>   **Type:** (Connection string)
>   **Scope:** Application
>   **Value:** DSN=Renta_Equipos

Now this is, normally the users log in without problems, but sometimes the connections gets closed for them (not all at the same time, 1-2 of 6 users experiment this) and the only way they can connect again is restarting the  client's PC, it happens randomly.

Error it gaves me:

> ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB] the SQL
>   server does not exist or access has been denied. ERROR
>   [01000][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Connection Open
>   (Connect())

I cannot find the problem, I know nothing about configuring an SQL server nor a professional programmer (all I know is from the Internet, books and some little help from other people), so I'm guessing it might be the server, but I can't get it, everything seems to be perfect (for me)

Here is a link for the Github source code: https://github.com/DarkLS/RentaEquipos.git

The error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O20ls.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all 6 of your client PCs desktops? If so, do the 1-2 users whom are having issues use a wired and/or wireless connection (some of the newer desktop towers have wireless capabilities)?

If it's going as far as denying access, you might be hitting your SQL user license cap (hard to say for sure)... Might want to review your SQL Server 2008 R2 environment with your IT guys.

**EDIT:** Check [this site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/195566)

Comment: all the six PCs are Desktop and Wired with non wireless capabilities, and yeah I found that article too, Named Pipes Protocol is alredy enable, so far it's working! I'll give it some time before saying it's fixed xD Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Definitely sounds like a weird SQL predicament, we're currently going through one of those right now as well. Glad I could be of assistance (thus far) :)